Weekly time lags
suppose to have the following dataset:
data dataset;
  input week_number Var1 Var2;
cards;
1  55  98
2  34  34
3  21  0
4  76  12
5  98  0
.. ... ..
52 21  43
;run;

what is the best way to calculate and add the following: lag of -1 week; lag of +1 week; lag of -2 weeks; lag of +2 weeks to the original dataset?
Thank you in advance

Using proc sql you can join the data with itself multiple times and control which weeks appear in each row with the join conditions:
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select have.*
            ,lag1.Var1 as Var1_lag1
            ,lag1.Var2 as Var2_lag1
            ,lag2.Var1 as Var1_lag2
            ,lag2.Var2 as Var2_lag2
            ,lead1.Var1 as Var1_lead1
            ,lead1.Var2 as Var2_lead1
            ,lead2.Var1 as Var1_lead2
            ,lead2.Var2 as Var2_lead2
    from dataset have left join dataset lag1 on lag1.Week_number = have.week_number - 1
                    left join dataset lag2 on lag2.week_number = have.week_number - 2
                    left join dataset lead1 on lead1.week_number = have.week_number + 1
                    left join dataset lead2 on lead2.week_number = have.week_number + 2
    ;
quit;

Variables with _lag1 have values from one week behind, _lag2 2 weeks behind, _lead1 1 week ahead and _lead2 2 weeks ahead.
